# getChildNodes() does not returning child nodes but the parent node itself

Tags: java, xml

I'm having an issue on getting child nodes of a tag from a parsed XML document. There are a few module tags inside the XML and these modules have child elements that respresents the module spesific data structures.

```java
Document nonBasicDoc = FO.parseXML(<XMLUrl>);
NodeList moduleList = nonBasicDoc.getElementsByTagName("module");
NodeList moduleChildNodes = Utility.getElementByAttribute(moduleList, "name", ModuleName).getChildNodes();
```

FO is my File Operations class, it uses Java parse API.

On the last line of this code, the statement should return the child nodes of the module but it's returning the module node itself.

For confidential reasons that's all I can share, but if anything like this is a common incident, I would like to hear some options.